# Run strapi headless CMS on raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberry-pi, strapi, headless

Simple quesion, it is posible run strapi headless CMS on raspberry pi 4?

I have search on google but I dont find direct answer.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that is possible install and run Strapi on Raspberry Pi.

I use command "npx create-strapi-app@latest test" and then run "npm run develop" inside test directory.
All working as spected.

[Install process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZcC1.png)

[run process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBecc.png)

[running gui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfevg.png)